# How to map the kronecker product along array dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jax, kronecker-product

Given two tensors A and B with the same dimension `(d>=2)` and shapes `[A_{1},...,A_{d-2},A_{d-1},A_{d}]` and `[A_{1},...,A_{d-2},B_{d-1},B_{d}]` (shapes of the first d-2 dimensions are identical).

Is there a way to calculate the kronecker product over the last two dimensions?
The shape of `my_kron(A,B)`should be `[A_{1},...,A_{d-2},A_{d-1}*B_{d-1},A_{d}*B_{d}]`.
For example with `d=3`,

```
A.shape=[2,3,3]
B.shape=[2,4,4]
C=my_kron(A,B)
```

`C[0,...]` should be the kronecker product of `A[0,...]` and `B[0,...]` and `C[1,...]` the kronecker product of `A[1,...]` and `B[1,...]`.

For d=2 this is simply what the `jnp.kron`(or `np.kron`) function does.

For d=3 this can be achived with `jax.vmap`.
`jax.vmap(lambda x, y: jnp.kron(x[0, :], y[0, :]))(A, B)`

But I was not able to find a solution for general (unknown) dimensions.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `np.einsum('...ij,...kl->...ikjl', a, b).reshape(*a.shape[:-2], a.shape[-2]*b.shape[-2], a.shape[-1]*b.shape[-1])`, IIUC. Please test this solution as I'm not sure about the generalization for more then 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `numpy` terms I think this is what you are doing:

```
In [104]: A = np.arange(2*3*3).reshape(2,3,3)
In [105]: B = np.arange(2*4*4).reshape(2,4,4)

In [106]: C = np.array([np.kron(a,b) for a,b in zip(A,B)])
In [107]: C.shape
Out[107]: (2, 12, 12)
```

That treats the initial dimension, the 2, as a `batch`.  One obvious generalization is to reshape the arrays, reducing the higher dimensions to 1, e.g. `reshape(-1,3,3)`, etc.  And then afterwards, reshape `C` back to the desired n-dimensions.

`np.kron` does accept 3d (and higher), but it's doing some sort of `outer` on the shared 2 dimension:

```
In [108]: np.kron(A,B).shape
Out[108]: (4, 12, 12)
```

And visualizing that 4 dimension as (2,2), I can take the `diagonal` and get your `C`:

```
In [109]: np.allclose(np.kron(A,B)[[0,3]], C)
Out[109]: True
```

The full `kron` does more calculations than needed, but is still faster:

```
In [110]: timeit C = np.array([np.kron(a,b) for a,b in zip(A,B)])
108 µs ± 2.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [111]: timeit np.kron(A,B)[[0,3]]
76.4 µs ± 1.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

I'm sure it's possible to do your calculation in a more direct way, but doing that requires a better understanding of how the `kron` works.  A quick glance as the `np.kron` code suggest that is does an `outer(A,B)`

```
In [114]: np.outer(A,B).shape
Out[114]: (18, 32)
```

which has the same number of elements, but it then `reshapes` and `concatenates` to produce the `kron` layout.

But following a hunch, I found that this is equivalent to what you want:

```
In [123]: D = A[:,:,None,:,None]*B[:,None,:,None,:]
In [124]: np.allclose(D.reshape(2,12,12),C)
Out[124]: True
In [125]: timeit np.reshape(A[:,:,None,:,None]*B[:,None,:,None,:],(2,12,12))
14.3 µs ± 184 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

That is easily generalized to more leading dimensions.

```
def my_kron(A,B):
   D = A[...,:,None,:,None]*B[...,None,:,None,:]
   ds = D.shape
   newshape = (*ds[:-4],ds[-4]*ds[-3],ds[-2]*ds[-1])
   return D.reshape(newshape)

In [137]: my_kron(A.reshape(1,2,1,3,3),B.reshape(1,2,1,4,4)).shape
Out[137]: (1, 2, 1, 12, 12)
```

Comment: That last one is nice. Almost makes me want to add an `axes` argument to `kron`

Comment: The last one is really nice.